# JQUERY: get the id's of the checked and not checked checkBox

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox

I have this not so many checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mango" value="mango" /> <label>MANGO</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="santol" value="santol" /> <label>SANTOL</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="guava" value="guava" /> <label>GUAVA</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="lomboy" value="lomboy" /> <label>LOMBOY</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="apple" value="apple" /> <label>APPLE</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="orange" value="orange" /> <label>ORANGE</label><br>
 ...................<>
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is get all the ID's of check boxes with check, and no check and put in an array. Something like this:

```
"fruitsGranted":["apple","lomboy","orange"]; //check is true
"fruitsDenied":["mango","santol","guava"];  //check false
```

can please someone show me how to do it.? thanks.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
var someObj={};
someObj.fruitsGranted=[];
someObj.fruitsDenied=[];

$("input:checkbox").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.is(":checked")){
        someObj.fruitsGranted.push($this.attr("id"));
    }else{
        someObj.fruitsDenied.push($this.attr("id"));
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UqrYJ/

Comment: how can I alert `fruitsGranted` and `fruitsDenied`?

Comment: `alert(someObj.fruitGranted);`  You don't need to have it in an object like that, it's just that your markup made it seem like you wanted an object.

Comment: @jayAnn: `alert ( someObj.fruitsGranted.join(",") );`

Comment: Added a fiddle to the answer.

Comment: @naveen the join is unneeded, alerting an array joins it anyway (unless some browsers don't)

Comment: is there any way to make it like an array, like this `["apple","lomboy","orange"]`?

Comment: It **IS** an array.  If you want to make a string that looks like that then you could join the array and append the ends on.  Something like:  `'["' + someObj.fruitsGranted.join('","') + '"]'`.  Untested, but that should work for all but the empty case.

Comment: why not using .map() method? see my answer below

Comment: @JamesMontagne I have a doubt.what does this statement means `var someObj={};`

Comment: @Techy `{}` is an empty object.

Answer (score 33):

I think I got a shorter version here:

```
var idSelector = function() { return this.id; };
var fruitsGranted = $(":checkbox:checked").map(idSelector).get();
var fruitsDenied = $(":checkbox:not(:checked)").map(idSelector).get();
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/XPMjK/3/

Comment: what is the requirement of get() function call here, it seems $(":checkbox:checked").map(idSelector) could do the job itself?

Comment: `.get()` converts a jquery array to a native array. I guess you could live without it too. -- you can testify the difference by calling a jquery function (e.g. `.find()`) on the outcome and you can see the difference

Answer (score 5):

I would do this something like this:

```
var all, checked, notChecked;
all = $("input:checkbox");
checked = all.filter(":checked");
notChecked = all.not(":checked)");
```

After that you can use jQuery.map to get the ids of each collection.

```
var checkedIds = checked.map(function() {
    return this.id;
});

var notCheckedIds = notChecked.map(function() {
    return this.id;
});
```

Comment: The `is()` function should be changed to the `filter()` function. The `is()` function returns boolean value.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), though in this case it is not really different from using `.each`:

```
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
    var notChecked = [], checked = [];
    $(":checkbox").map(function() {
        this.checked ? checked.push(this.id) : notChecked.push(this.id);
    });
    alert("checked: " + checked);
    alert("not checked: " + notChecked);
});
```

[**You can test it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/eTG6p/4/)