# Javascript when checkbox is checked, add checkbox ID to an array

Tags: javascript, html

I am defining an array of checked checkboxes:

```
<script>
var all_checked = new Array();
function add_checked(checked_checkbox_id)
{
all_checked.push(checked_checkbox_id);
}

<html>
<input type="checkbox" name="a" id="1" value="1" onclick="add_checked(?????);" />
</html>
```

So my question is how to pass the checked checkbox ID to the function to append to the global

> all_checked

variable

Comment: take a look of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901242/jquery-get-the-ids-of-the-checked-and-not-checked-checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `this` in your function and then use it to get the `id` property:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a" id="1" value="1" onclick="add_checked(this);" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
var all_checked = new Array();
function add_checked(el) {
    all_checked.push(el.id);
}
```

Remember, this will push the `id` to the array no matter what, whether the box is checked or unchecked, even if the `id` already exists in the array.

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/rWtg6/)

Answer (score 1):

Use **`this`** keyword by passing to yout function.

```
 onclick="add_checked(this)";
```

Here you can the id as

```
this.id
```

then in

```
function add_checked(checked_checkbox) {
  all_checked.push(checked_checkbox.id);
}
```

**FYI:**  `script` tag should be within `html` tag

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<button onclick="send_query(document.getElementsByTagName('input'))">

function send_query(check) {

    var values = [];
    for (i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
        if (check[i].checked == true) {
            values.push(check[i].value);
        }
    }
    console.log(values.join());
}
```