# how to get the ids of checked checkboxes in jquery

Tags: html, jquery, checkbox

I want to get the ids of checked checkboxes and store those ids in an array using jquery.
Can anybody give me correct code for it.

I have tried

Thanks in advance :)

```
$("#merge_button").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var searchIDs = $("#find-table input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
        return $(this).val();
    }).toArray();
    console.log(searchIDs);
});
```

Comment: You can change `return $(this).val();` to `this.id`

Comment: i got it but its does returns array

Comment: it is giving comma seperated value.. I cant loop through it

Comment: It gives an array of ids, which you can loop over if you want.

Comment: can you give an example code to loop that result

Comment: `searchIDs.forEach(function(id) { /* your code here */ });` Also, change `toArray()` to `get()`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v1ferwyb/ you might not even need an array depending on what you're trying to do with the ids

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan now I'm curiois, what is the different between `.get()` and `.toArray()` in this context?

Comment: @kowshiga, I gave the answer. Do you need such a result?

Comment: @NickParsons to be honest, I can't remember exactly what they are, and in this case when dealing with a basic int type it should be fine to use either. However I've had cases in the past where `toArray()` has caused issues that `get()` has resolved.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ah I see, thanks. I'll keep that in mind in case I ran into any issue with `.toArray()` down the line

Comment: Actually looking at the source it would appear that `toArray()` and `get()` are now almost identical and both use calls to `slice()`, so in a modern version of jQuery there is no difference.

Comment: Duplicate of [JQUERY: get the id's of the checked and not checked checkBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901242/jquery-get-the-ids-of-the-checked-and-not-checked-checkbox)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `attr()` method to get **id**. Like this:

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

Do you need such a result?

```js
$("#merge_button").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var searchIDs = $("#find-table input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
        return $(this).attr('id');
    }).toArray();
    console.log(searchIDs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="find-table">
  <input id="1" type="checkbox">
  <input id="2" type="checkbox">
  <input id="3" type="checkbox">
</div>

<button id="merge_button">merge</button>
```